# Angular 8 P-dialog - ipad - responsiveness issue

Tags: angular, primeng

[image: p-dialog-not showing close symbol]We have used PrimeNG p-dialog box. Its showing with maximize and close button on regular desktop sizes. But when we go to ipad view, dialog maximize and close button seems unreachable. 
Below is p-dialog with [responsive]="true" added already. What else is needed? any other attribute ?

```
<p-dialog [modal]="true" [(visible)]="display" [responsive]="true" appendTo="body" >
<div>contents goes here</div>
</p-dialog>
```

Answer (score 1):

primeng is not responsive in some resolutions you can use css. try this.

```
@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .ui-dialog{
       left: 50%;
       width: 500px;
       margin-left: -250px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your hint Ankush.
Below code worked -

```
@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
    body .ui-dialog {
        margin-left: 5px;
        margin-right: -10px;
    }
}
```